# Why ghc 8.8.4 can't compile a file that ghci can load?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

In Mac OS 10.15.7, with haskell platform installed, I am having a weird behavior. The code works fine in ghci but the linking during compilation is not working:

```
% ghc Merge.hs
Loaded package environment from /Users/ar/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.8.4/environments/default
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Merge.hs, Merge.o ) [Optimisation flags changed]
Linking Merge ...
ld: can't open output file for writing: Merge, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

But ghci works fine:

```
% ghci Merge.hs
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /Users/ar/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.8.4/environments/default
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Merge.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main>
```

Also, `% stack runghc -- Merge` works but

```
% stack ghc -- Merge
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Merge.hs, Merge.o ) [Data.Aeson changed]
Linking Merge ...
ld: can't open output file for writing: Merge, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Any idea? I have installed the haskell platform following the instructions in https://www.haskell.org/downloads/ with https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html (ghcup).

Code is https://gist.github.com/arademaker/e7ae2e1ef5225807a3e627caa61481da

Comment: Do you by any chance already have a directory named `Merge` in your directory (or something else that can cause a name clash)?

Comment: Oh... @WillemVanOnsem, thank you. I am so embraced, I have been trying to understand stack vs haskell platform and how to deal with packages etc. Yes, I have created a directory in the same folder with the same name and I forgot about it...

Comment: well it happened to me as well a few years ago :). It is often not the first think that one thinks of :)

Comment: Indeed, `errno=21` is `EISDIR` "Is a directory". On one hand, I'm glad `ld` printed that. OTOH, it could have printed a more human readable message.

Answer (score 3):

I had a directory with the same name in the folder! My mistake.